# Top ad banner Prestashop 1.7.1

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to understand how this top banner (SALE 70% OFF ALL PRODUCTS) included in this image can be done:

https://medias2.prestastore.com/906398-pbig/banner-manager.jpg

Is it needed an extra module for that?
If so, which one?
If not, how can you modify the theme to include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Banner Block (blocbanner in files) module, included by default, that you can manage in your backoffice.