# Prestashop 1.7.1 - Top banner which hook shall be used?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274748/top-ad-banner-prestashop-1-7-1) I have created a new banner.
Now I want to insert a hook, but I am wondering which hook shall be used to display it on top of every page (as a promotional banner).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the classic theme, you can use the `displayBanner` hook. If you look at `header.tpl` you can find the following block:

```
{block name='header_banner'}
   <div class="header-banner">
     {hook h='displayBanner'}
   </div>
{/block}
```

which should be displayed on top of every page