# Prestashop 1.7.1 - Register a new hook

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to display a top banner in my theme (which is not the default classic one).

Specifically I modify header.tpl to include this (as in classic theme):

```
{block name='header_banner'}
   <div class="header-banner">
     {hook h='displayBanner'}
   </div>
{/block}
```

But displayBanner does not appear as a valid hook to attach modules to it.
Do I have to register the hook somewhere else? If so, which would be the code?

This question further elaborates [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289650/prestashop-1-7-1-top-banner-which-hook-shall-be-used/47304088#47304088).
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Registering hooks happens in a modules `install` method.

You can do the following for example in your module:

```
public function install()
{
    $installed = (parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayBanner'));

    if ( $installed ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $this->uninstall();

      return false;
    }
}
```

then uninstall and reinstall your module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your new hook into a theme.yml and set up the module on it, and after that just reset your theme to default Design->Theme & Logo->Reset to defaults. 
*theme.yml*
hooks:
    modules_to_hook:
        displayBanner:
          - your_module_name
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WRUp.png)
Caveat: after resetting your theme will look like it is set up in the theme.yml file. If you have done any changes in the theme appearance from admin panel and didn't include it in theme.yml they gonna be lost.